# Making two identical PDFs using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to clone a pdf, and make slight changes to the document at some point during or after copying.

I managed to do that with the pages but I am trying to copy also all metadata, form fields, acrofields etc.

How will I be able to do that using iTextSharp ?

```
Document document = new Document(); 
FileStream fs = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, fs);
document.Open();
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    PdfImportedPage importedPage = copy.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
    copy.AddPage(importedPage);
}
copy.Outlines = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);                

fs.Flush();

PdfCopyFields copyf = new PdfCopyFields(fs);
```

Comment: probably a dumb comment, but how about just copying the pdf file?

Comment: heh.. no i want to make slight changes to the document.

Comment: Well, couldn't you copy the file, then make changes to it (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508120/adding-text-to-existing-pdf-which-is-closed-using-itextsharp)?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make identical-byte copies with iTextSharp. You can make identical copies with System.IO.File.Copy.

You are then free to open it with iTextSharp to make further adjustments to the copy.

Answer (score 0):

You use a `PdfCopy` based solution.

For your task, though, i.e. to take a single PDF and apply some changes to it, the appropriate solution is `PdfStamper` based. That would look like this:

```
PdfReader reader = ...;
[...apply changes using PdfReader methods...]
FileStream fs = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
[...apply changes using PdfStamper methods...]
stamper.Close();
```